# systemd service file always does start and stop

Tags: systemd

have created a new systemd service for botpress If I do

> systemctl start botpress.service

it Starts all the botpress stuff then immeaditly runs the ExecStop stuff.  Systemctl starts fine if I remove ExecStop=.......

the script being called works just fine.

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/botpress.service 
[Unit]
Description=botpess
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=simple

TimeoutStartSec=5s
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'echo ">>>>>>>>>>> pre-starting botpress <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"'
ExecStart=/etc/systemd/system/botpress.initd start
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c 'echo ">>>>>>>>>>> post-starting botpress <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"'


ExecStop=/etc/systemd/system/botpress.initd stop
ExecStopPost=/bin/bash -c 'echo ">>>>>>>>>>> post-stopping botpress <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can put put the botpress.initd script in /etc/init.d and get systemctl to stop and start but will not restart at reboot.   all I want to do is just call a simple script that can start and stop on demand and enable at reboot

```
cat botpress.initd 
#! /bin/bash -x 
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          my-service-name
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: your description here
### END INIT INFO

BOTPRESS_COMPOSE_HOME="/home/pcooke/tmp/botpress/examples/docker-compose/"
COMPOSE_YAML="docker-compose-pro-nginx.yaml"
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
#OPTIONS="--verbose"

start() {
  echo "starting botpress"
  /usr/local/bin/docker-compose ${OPTIONS} -f ${COMPOSE_YAML} up -d  --build
}

stop() {
  echo "stopping botpress"
  /usr/local/bin/docker-compose ${OPTIONS} -f ${COMPOSE_YAML} down
}


cd ${BOTPRESS_COMPOSE_HOME}

case "$1" in
        start)
            start
            ;;

        stop)
            stop
            ;;
        restart)
            stop
            start
            ;;
        *)
            echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
            exit 1

esac
```

```
root@pcooke-XPS-13-9370:/etc/systemd/system# journalctl -xe
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[4029]: [263B blob data]
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[4029]: Removing botpress-server ...
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[4029]: Removing redis           ...
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[4029]: Removing botpress-lang   ...
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[4029]: Removing postgres        ...
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[4029]: [274B blob data]
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: Interface br-e6bd415385a8.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface br-e6bd415385a8.IPv6 with address fe80::42:9fff:fe45:b457.
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: Interface br-e6bd415385a8.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface br-e6bd415385a8.IPv4 with address 172.27.0.1.
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::42:9fff:fe45:b457 on br-e6bd415385a8.
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: Withdrawing address record for 172.27.0.1 on br-e6bd415385a8.
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 NetworkManager[849]: <info>  [1586319650.5374] device (br-e6bd415385a8): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 dbus-daemon[824]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.10' (u
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 gnome-shell[2943]: Removing a network device that was not added
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun starting up.
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 gnome-shell[1161]: Removing a network device that was not added
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 dbus-daemon[824]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 nm-dispatcher[4557]: req:1 'down' [br-e6bd415385a8]: new request (2 scripts)
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 nm-dispatcher[4557]: req:1 'down' [br-e6bd415385a8]: start running ordered scripts...
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 NetworkManager[849]: <info>  [1586319650.5626] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/br-e6bd415385a8, iface: br-e6bd415385a8)
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 07 21:20:50 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 bash[4641]: >>>>>>>>>>> post-stopping botpress <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Apr 07 21:20:51 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 07 21:20:51 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 07 21:20:51 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 07 21:20:51 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 07 21:20:51 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 07 21:20:51 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 07 21:20:53 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced fe
/////
```

after changing type to onshot and restarting

```
root@pcoo/ke-XPS-13-9370:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl start botpress
Job for botpress.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status botpress.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
 systemctl status botpress
● botpress.service - botpess
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/botpress.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2020-04-08 19:14:33 PDT; 5min ago
  Process: 11561 ExecStopPost=/bin/bash -c echo ">>>>>>>>>>> post-stopping botpress <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11026 ExecStart=/etc/systemd/system/botpress.initd start (code=killed, signal=TERM)
  Process: 11025 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c echo ">>>>>>>>>>> pre-starting botpress <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11026 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Apr 08 19:14:30 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[11026]: Successfully tagged docker-compose_nginx:latest
Apr 08 19:14:30 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[11026]: Creating postgres ...
Apr 08 19:14:30 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[11026]: Creating redis    ...
Apr 08 19:14:30 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[11026]: Creating botpress-lang ...
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: botpress.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: botpress.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[11026]: [90B blob data]
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 bash[11561]: >>>>>>>>>>> post-stopping botpress <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: botpress.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Failed to start botpess.
```

new journalctl -xe

```
journalctl -xe
Apr 08 19:14:32 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 08 19:14:32 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 08 19:14:32 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 kernel: eth0: renamed from vethfbd729e
Apr 08 19:14:32 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 NetworkManager[849]: <info>  [1586398472.3620] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethfbd729e, iface: vethfbd729e)
Apr 08 19:14:32 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethaec5c13: link becomes ready
Apr 08 19:14:32 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 kernel: br-83455e030a4d: port 1(vethaec5c13) entered blocking state
Apr 08 19:14:32 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 kernel: br-83455e030a4d: port 1(vethaec5c13) entered forwarding state
Apr 08 19:14:32 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 NetworkManager[849]: <info>  [1586398472.3647] device (vethaec5c13): carrier: link connected
Apr 08 19:14:32 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 gnome-shell[2943]: Removing a network device that was not added
Apr 08 19:14:32 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 gnome-shell[1161]: Removing a network device that was not added
Apr 08 19:14:32 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface br-83455e030a4d.IPv6 with address fe80::42:76ff:fe65:828.
Apr 08 19:14:32 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: New relevant interface br-83455e030a4d.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 08 19:14:32 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: Registering new address record for fe80::42:76ff:fe65:828 on br-83455e030a4d.*.
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface veth9ba683a.IPv6 with address fe80::877:c1ff:fe8d:4ccf.
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: New relevant interface veth9ba683a.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: Registering new address record for fe80::877:c1ff:fe8d:4ccf on veth9ba683a.*.
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 kernel: eth0: renamed from vethbde55a8
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 NetworkManager[849]: <info>  [1586398473.3297] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethbde55a8, iface: vethbde55a8)
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth1583c41: link becomes ready
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 kernel: br-83455e030a4d: port 3(veth1583c41) entered blocking state
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 kernel: br-83455e030a4d: port 3(veth1583c41) entered forwarding state
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 NetworkManager[849]: <info>  [1586398473.3324] device (veth1583c41): carrier: link connected
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 gnome-shell[1161]: Removing a network device that was not added
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 gnome-shell[2943]: Removing a network device that was not added
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: botpress.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: botpress.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[11026]: [90B blob data]
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 bash[11561]: >>>>>>>>>>> post-stopping botpress <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: botpress.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Apr 08 19:14:33 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Failed to start botpess.
-- Subject: Unit botpress.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit botpress.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Apr 08 19:14:34 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface vethaec5c13.IPv6 with address fe80::60f4:dfff:fe0a:ff72.
Apr 08 19:14:34 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: New relevant interface vethaec5c13.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 08 19:14:34 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: Registering new address record for fe80::60f4:dfff:fe0a:ff72 on vethaec5c13.*.
Apr 08 19:14:34 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface veth1583c41.IPv6 with address fe80::d4ce:bdff:fedc:6e74.
Apr 08 19:14:34 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: New relevant interface veth1583c41.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 08 19:14:34 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 avahi-daemon[817]: Registering new address record for fe80::d4ce:bdff:fedc:6e74 on veth1583c41.*.
Apr 08 19:14:37 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 08 19:14:37 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 08 19:14:37 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 08 19:14:37 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 08 19:14:37 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 08 19:14:37 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[641]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 08 19:17:01 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 CRON[11653]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 08 19:17:01 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 CRON[11654]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr 08 19:17:01 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 CRON[11653]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

what is interesting is: after enabling botpress and a reboot now all but nginx container starts

```
 systemctl status botpress
● botpress.service - botpess
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/botpress.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2020-04-08 19:27:24 PDT; 2min 52s ago
  Process: 2490 ExecStopPost=/bin/bash -c echo ">>>>>>>>>>> post-stopping botpress <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1677 ExecStart=/etc/systemd/system/botpress.initd start (code=killed, signal=TERM)
  Process: 1676 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c echo ">>>>>>>>>>> pre-starting botpress <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1677 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Apr 08 19:27:20 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[1677]: Successfully tagged docker-compose_nginx:latest
Apr 08 19:27:20 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[1677]: Starting botpress-lang ...
Apr 08 19:27:20 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[1677]: Starting redis         ...
Apr 08 19:27:20 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[1677]: Starting postgres      ...
Apr 08 19:27:23 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 botpress.initd[1677]: [163B blob data]
Apr 08 19:27:24 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: botpress.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Apr 08 19:27:24 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: botpress.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Apr 08 19:27:24 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 bash[2490]: >>>>>>>>>>> post-stopping botpress <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Apr 08 19:27:24 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: botpress.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Apr 08 19:27:24 pcooke-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Failed to start botpess.
```

when I just have ExecStart I get no mention of tagging NGINX.  Here is my compse file.

```
cat docker-compose-pro-nginx.yaml 
version: '3.7'

services:
  botpress:
    build:
      context: ./botpress
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: botpress-server
    container_name: botpress-server
    command: bash -c "export AUTO_MIGRATE=true; ./bp --auto-update"
    expose:
      - 3000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:secretpw@postgres:5435/botpress_db
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379?password=redisPassword
      - BP_MODULE_NLU_DUCKLINGURL=http://botpress_lang:8000
      - BP_MODULE_NLU_LANGUAGESOURCES=[{"endpoint":"http://botpress_lang:3100"}]
      - EXTERNAL_URL=https://botpressdev.sf.frb.org
      - CLUSTER_ENABLED=true
      - PRO_ENABLED=true
      - BP_PRODUCTION=true
      - BPFS_STORAGE=database
      - BP_LICENSE_KEY=123456789
    depends_on:
      - botpress_lang
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - /opt/botpress-data/botpress:/botpress/data

  botpress_lang:
    build:
      context: ./botpress
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: botpress-lang
    container_name: botpress-lang
    command: bash -c "./duckling -p 8000 & ./bp lang --langDir /botpress/lang --port 3100"
    expose:
      - 3100
      - 8000
    volumes:
      - /opt/botpress-data/language:/botpress/lang

  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.2-alpine
    expose:
      - 5435
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      PGPORT: 5435
      POSTGRES_DB: botpress_db
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secretpw
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    volumes:
      - /opt/botpress-data/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.5-alpine
    expose:
      - 6379
    container_name: redis
    command: redis-server --requirepass redisPassword
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    command: nginx -g 'daemon off';
    depends_on:
      - botpress

volumes:
  redisdata:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well well I feel like the fresh college grad with no experience.

Talking with vendor all I needed was to add "restart: always" to my compose file and let docker do the rest.

```
    services:
      botpress:
        build:
          context: ./botpress
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: botpress-serve
        restart: always
        container_name: botpress-server
        command: bash -c "export AUTO_MIGRATE=true; ./bp --auto-update"
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though it may be a "one shot" command.

What that means is that you start the process with systemd then as soon as it is up and running systemd takes over responsibility for it and runs it in the background. The process ID was only needed to start it, not to keep it running.

To test, please run and show the outcome here, of :
`systemctl status botpress.service` - amend "botpress" if that is not the actual  name of the package.

To start the process as a systemd unit at boot, run `sytemctl enable botpress.service` at anytime before the next reboot. Now would be good.

Comment: I added the info you suggested

Comment: Since which the error has changed to timed out. Something is preventing it from starting. Did you have to manually change type to oneshot? That means it wasn't. I am not familiar with botpress so really can't help you with it. However, I did see botpess instead of botpress twice in your botpress status report. Are you hand-copying these? If not it may be worth checking whether something went wrong at installation, unless you know botpess actually means something. Apart from that, you need somebody who is more up to date with containerisation (docker specifically) than I.

Comment: i chagedti to oneshot and nothing changed in behavior.  The problem seems to be the nginx container being started by systemctl.   "watch -n 1 docker ps -a" is showing me that everything seems to come up fine until the nginx container.  once it starts bringing up nginx systemd records a network error.